# Calculate throughput in NS2 using AWK

Tags: networking, network-programming, awk, ns2, throughput

[image]
My senario in NS 2.29 has 5 nodes which each node has 2 interfaces to expect node 0 and node 4 and node 0 wants to send packet to node 4. The protocol I've used is AODV and type of nodes is wireless

I want to calculate

receive packet / send packet

and also throughput  in different simulation time and I want to do all with AWK language.

I dont know how to share output file to undrestand what I said.

output file :

```
s -t 0.100000000 -Hs 0 -Hd -2 -Ni 0 -Nx 0.00 -Ny 500.00 -Nz 0.00 -Ne -1.000000 -Nl AGT -Nw --- -Ma 0 -Md 0 -Ms 0 -Mt 0 -Is 0.0 -Id 4.0 -It cbr -Il 1000 -If 1 -Ii 0 -Iv 32 -Pn cbr -Pi 0 -Pf 0 -Po 0 

r -t 0.100000000 -Hs 0 -Hd -2 -Ni 0 -Nx 0.00 -Ny 500.00 -Nz 0.00 -Ne -1.000000 -Nl RTR -Nw --- -Ma 0 -Md 0 -Ms 0 -Mt 0 -Is 0.0 -Id 4.0 -It cbr -Il 1000 -If 1 -Ii 0 -Iv 32 -Pn cbr -Pi 0 -Pf 0 -Po 0 

s 0.100000000 _0_ RTR  --- 0 AODV 48 [0 0 0 0] ------- [0:255 -1:255 30 0] [0x2 1 1 [4 0] [0 4]] (REQUEST)

s -t 0.100295000 -Hs 0 -Hd -2 -Ni 0 -Nx 0.00 -Ny 500.00 -Nz 0.00 -Ne -1.000000 -Nl MAC -Nw --- -Ma 0 -Md ffffffff -Ms 0 -Mt 800 -Is 0.255 -Id -1.255 -It AODV -Il 100 -If 0 -Ii 0 -Iv 30 -P aodv -Pt 0x2 -Ph 1 -Pb 1 -Pd 4 -Pds 0 -Ps 0 -Pss 4 -Pc REQUEST 

r -t 0.101095133 -Hs 1 -Hd -2 -Ni 1 -Nx 40.00 -Ny 500.00 -Nz 0.00 -Ne -1.000000 -Nl MAC -Nw --- -Ma 0 -Md ffffffff -Ms 0 -Mt 800 -Is 0.255 -Id -1.255 -It AODV -Il 48 -If 0 -Ii 0 -Iv 30 -P aodv -Pt 0x2 -Ph 1 -Pb 1 -Pd 4 -Pds 0 -Ps 0 -Pss 4 -Pc REQUEST 

r -t 0.101120133 -Hs 1 -Hd -2 -Ni 1 -Nx 40.00 -Ny 500.00 -Nz 0.00 -Ne -1.000000 -Nl RTR -Nw --- -Ma 0 -Md ffffffff -Ms 0 -Mt 800 -Is 0.255 -Id -1.255 -It AODV -Il 48 -If 0 -Ii 0 -Iv 30 -P aodv -Pt 0x2 -Ph 1 -Pb 1 -Pd 4 -Pds 0 -Ps 0 -Pss 4 -Pc REQUEST 

s 0.102001360 _1_ RTR  --- 0 AODV 48 [0 ffffffff 0 800] ------- [1:255 -1:255 29 0] [0x2 2 1 [4 0] [0 4]] (REQUEST)

s -t 0.102476360 -Hs 1 -Hd -2 -Ni 1 -Nx 40.00 -Ny 500.00 -Nz 0.00 -Ne -1.000000 -Nl MAC -Nw --- -Ma 0 -Md ffffffff -Ms 1 -Mt 800 -Is 1.255 -Id -1.255 -It AODV -Il 100 -If 0 -Ii 0 -Iv 29 -P aodv -Pt 0x2 -Ph 2 -Pb 1 -Pd 4 -Pds 0 -Ps 0 -Pss 4 -Pc REQUEST 

r -t 0.103276493 -Hs 0 -Hd -2 -Ni 0 -Nx 0.00 -Ny 500.00 -Nz 0.00 -Ne -1.000000 -Nl MAC -Nw --- -Ma 0 -Md ffffffff -Ms 1 -Mt 800 -Is 1.255 -Id -1.255 -It AODV -Il 48 -If 0 -Ii 0 -Iv 29 -P aodv -Pt 0x2 -Ph 2 -Pb 1 -Pd 4 -Pds 0 -Ps 0 -Pss 4 -Pc REQUEST 

r -t 0.103301493 -Hs 0 -Hd -2 -Ni 0 -Nx 0.00 -Ny 500.00 -Nz 0.00 -Ne -1.000000 -Nl RTR -Nw --- -Ma 0 -Md ffffffff -Ms 1 -Mt 800 -Is 1.255 -Id -1.255 -It AODV -Il 48 -If 0 -Ii 0 -Iv 29 -P aodv -Pt 0x2 -Ph 2 -Pb 1 -Pd 4 -Pds 0 -Ps 0 -Pss 4 -Pc REQUEST 

s 0.105531867 _1_ RTR  --- 0 AODV 48 [0 ffffffff 0 800] ------- [1:255 -1:255 29 0] [0x2 2 1 [4 0] [0 4]] (REQUEST)

s -t 0.105786867 -Hs 1 -Hd -2 -Ni 1 -Nx 40.00 -Ny 500.00 -Nz 0.00 -Ne -1.000000 -Nl MAC -Nw --- -Ma 0 -Md ffffffff -Ms 2 -Mt 800 -Is 1.255 -Id -1.255 -It AODV -Il 100 -If 0 -Ii 0 -Iv 29 -P aodv -Pt 0x2 -Ph 2 -Pb 1 -Pd 4 -Pds 0 -Ps 0 -Pss 4 -Pc REQUEST 

r -t 0.106587000 -Hs 2 -Hd -2 -Ni 2 -Nx 80.00 -Ny 500.00 -Nz 0.00 -Ne -1.000000 -Nl MAC -Nw --- -Ma 0 -Md ffffffff -Ms 2 -Mt 800 -Is 1.255 -Id -1.255 -It AODV -Il 48 -If 0 -Ii 0 -Iv 29 -P aodv -Pt 0x2 -Ph 2 -Pb 1 -Pd 4 -Pds 0 -Ps 0 -Pss 4 -Pc REQUEST 

r -t 0.106612000 -Hs 2 -Hd -2 -Ni 2 -Nx 80.00 -Ny 500.00 -Nz 0.00 -Ne -1.000000 -Nl RTR -Nw --- -Ma 0 -Md ffffffff -Ms 2 -Mt 800 -Is 1.255 -Id -1.255 -It AODV -Il 48 -If 0 -Ii 0 -Iv 29 -P aodv -Pt 0x2 -Ph 2 -Pb 1 -Pd 4 -Pds 0 -Ps 0 -Pss 4 -Pc REQUEST 

s 0.109702791 _2_ RTR  --- 0 AODV 48 [0 ffffffff 2 800] ------- [2:255 -1:255 28 0] [0x2 3 1 [4 0] [0 4]] (REQUEST)

s -t 0.110077791 -Hs 2 -Hd -2 -Ni 2 -Nx 80.00 -Ny 500.00 -Nz 0.00 -Ne -1.000000 -Nl MAC -Nw --- -Ma 0 -Md ffffffff -Ms 4 -Mt 800 -Is 2.255 -Id -1.255 -It AODV -Il 100 -If 0 -Ii 0 -Iv 28 -P aodv -Pt 0x2 -Ph 3 -Pb 1 -Pd 4 -Pds 0 -Ps 0 -Pss 4 -Pc REQUEST
```

....

to be continue

Can anybody explain how can I do this?
Any answer will be very helpfull.
Thanks

Comment: if you specify your question a bit, you would have more chances to get good answers.  e.g. what input do you have, what output/result are you expecting, better specify the problem as well, e.g. what have you tried, where were you stuck..

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I don't know how to calculate throghput in awk. my input is trace file from NS2.

Comment: Is [this](http://nsnam.isi.edu/nsnam/index.php/Main_Page) "NS2"? Please provide some sample data with an explanation of it and show how the data should be processed into "throughput". It is more likely that someone here can help you who knows AWK but doesn't know NS2 than it is to find someone who knows NS2 as evidenced by the fact that there are 2231 [tag:awk] questions and only 83 [tag:ns2] questions. Also, people will be more willing to help if you show that you've put some effort into solving your own problem and ask specific questions rather than broad, general ones.

Comment: I have shortened the data since there was way too much. Please explain the meaning of the significant fields (you don't need to explain fields that can be ignored). The answer I have already given is, in principle, the technique you will need to use. Please try to apply it to what you're doing. I've edited it so it might be a little more helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say you have the following two data lines which consist of a timestamp and a number of bytes sent during the time interval ending with that timestamp:

```
s 1341227109 10010
r 1341227111 19115
s 1341227118 12345
r 1341227122 16773
```

This snippet would calculate the throughput during the time interval between the two events:

```
awk '! sprev && $1 == "s" {sprev = $2; next} $1 == "s" {sinterval = $2 - sprev; sthroughput = $2 / sinterval; print sthroughput, "sent bytes/second"}' inputfile
```

add similar blocks for received data. You can use arrays to track node to node communication separately if needed.

Issues to be addressed:

- Do you want to output throughput for each interval? Probably not. Is it good enough to use the first and last event only? Do you want to do some sort of moving calculation taking some number of events or larger segements of time?
- Are there different types of events that need to be accounted separately?
- Is there data to be ignored or used in setup?

It looks to me that the more natural choice for processing NS2 data might be TCL since it appears to be used within the package and there may be APIs that you can take advantage of. However, AWK is perfectly suited for processing tabular data.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edit question and hope to explain question better.